# No write access to samba share

Tags: samba

## Scenario

- Kubuntu desktop 18.04, tower
- Lubuntu desktop 18.04, laptop
- Windows 10, laptop

## Kubuntu

- I installed and configured samba server as per [Install and Configure Samba in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver](https://www.computerbeginnersguides.com/blog/2018/04/27/install-and-configure-samba-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver/)
- My addition to `/etc/smb.conf`:

```
[kubuntu_home]
   path = /home/myusername
   available = yes
   valid users = myusername
   read only = no
   browseable = yes
   public = yes
   writable = yes
```

- I thought that there was a typo on the website, but when I checked it out on [samba.org](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html), I found that `writable` is a synonym for `writeable`.

## Lubuntu

- I mounted the samba share as per [How to Mount Samba Share in Ubuntu Linux](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/mount-samba-share-ubuntu-cifs/)

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=myusername,password=mypassword //192.168.###.###/kubuntu_home /mnt/kubuntu_home
```

## Windows

- I mounted the samba share as per [How to connect to Linux Samba shares from Windows 10](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-connect-to-linux-samba-shares-from-windows-10/)

## Problem

**From Lubuntu, I can read files but cannot write.**

- From Kubuntu, `ls -l ~` shows files and directories as belonging to `myusername myusername`.
- From Lubuntu, `ls -l /mnt/kubuntu_home/` displays all files and folders as belonging to `root root`.
- Somewhere along the way, I saw a suggestion to add `force user = myusername` to `smb.conf`. This did not make a difference.
- No problems reading/writing from Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take possession of the mounted share so that it's owned by you not root.

Change this:

> $ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=myusername,password=mypassword
>   //192.168.###.###/kubuntu_home /mnt/kubuntu_home

To this:

> $ sudo mount -t cifs -o
>   username=myusername,password=mypassword,uid=1000
>   //192.168.###.###/kubuntu_home /mnt/kubuntu_home

By adding **uid=1000** to the list of options.

Note: Your uid number on the Lubuntu machine may not be 1000. To verify that number run `id` in a terminal and change the mount command if necessary.

Comment: Thanks very much @Morbius1!